# Edit XML base with vb

Tags: xml, vb.net

i'm trying to edit this xml data base:

```
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="fr-FR" mode="voice" root="rulemerci" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics/1.0">
  <rule id="rulemerci" scope="public">
    <example>Salut SARAH!</example>
    <tag>out.action=new Object();</tag>

    <one-of>
      <item>Bonjour SARAH! comment vas tu?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "Je vais trés bien merci! et toi?"</tag></item>
      <item>Bonjour SARAH, tu vas bien?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "oui merci! et toi?"</tag></item>
      <item>Bonsoir SARAH! comment vas tu?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "ca va bien! et toi?"</tag></item>
    </one-of>
    
  </rule> 
</grammar>
```

want to add /remove items in one-of, without reseting all my file, can't figure how ...

i've tried like this, actually my item is good, but it reset all the file ...

```
Function writeXML()
        Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim output As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim file As String = My.Settings.folder + "\plugins\Hello\Hello.xml"
        Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(file, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        writer.WriteStartDocument(True)

        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        writer.Indentation = 4

        writer.WriteStartElement("one-of")
        createXmlRec(input, output, writer)

        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndDocument()
        writer.Close()

        MsgBox("Fonction Ajouté !")
    End Function
    Function createXmlRec(ByVal input As String, ByVal output As String, ByVal writer As XmlTextWriter)
        writer.WriteStartElement("item")
        writer.WriteString(input)


        writer.WriteStartElement("tag")
        writer.WriteString("out.action._attributes.tts = """ + output + """")
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteEndElement()
    End Function
```

Thank you for help

Comment: What does "without reseting all my file" mean?  Do you not want to write your changes back?  What exactly is the problem?  Maybe edit your question with the expected output

Comment: ok i posted it after

Comment: hop you can help me

Answer (score 0):

ok this is my xml

```
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="fr-FR" mode="voice" root="rulemerci" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics/1.0">
  <rule id="rulemerci" scope="public">
    <example>Salut SARAH!</example>
    <tag>out.action=new Object();</tag>

    <one-of>
      <item>Bonjour SARAH! comment vas tu?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "Je vais trés bien merci! et toi?"</tag></item>
      <item>Bonjour SARAH, tu vas bien?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "oui merci! et toi?"</tag></item>
      <item>Bonsoir SARAH! comment vas tu?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "ca va bien! et toi?"</tag></item>
    </one-of>
    
  </rule> 
</grammar>
```

and i want it to look like :

```
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="fr-FR" mode="voice" root="rulemerci" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics/1.0">
  <rule id="rulemerci" scope="public">
    <example>Salut SARAH!</example>
    <tag>out.action=new Object();</tag>

    <one-of>
      <item>Bonjour SARAH! comment vas tu?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "Je vais trés bien merci! et toi?"</tag></item>
      <item>Bonjour SARAH, tu vas bien?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "oui merci! et toi?"</tag></item>
      <item>Bonsoir SARAH! comment vas tu?<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "ca va bien! et toi?"</tag></item>
      <item>First string added<tag>out.action._attributes.tts = "Second string added"</tag></item>
    </one-of>
    
  </rule> 
</grammar>
```